# Replace text containing brackets and quote entity in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, find-replace

I am trying to run a query in MariaDB 10.3 that will replace `[google]&quot;` with `[google]` in SMF:

`UPDATE smf_messages SET body = REPLACE(body, '[google]&quot;', '[google]') WHERE ID_BOARD = 64`

This query has worked for me for normal text, but now it gives me

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''[google]&quot)' at line 1`

Comment: The query you posted and the portion of the query causing the error doesn't match. There's no `)` after `&quot` in your query, in the error message it is. [Edit] the question and provide a example, i.e. a query that actually produces the error.

Comment: Actually, that is verbatim the query and the error displayed. I am aware that they do not match.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ykwHCNL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am understanding you right you are searching for the  escape character

```
UPDATE smf_messages SET body = REPLACE(body, '\'[google]&quot;', '\'[google]') WHERE ID_BOARD = 64
```

This would look for a single quote before the bracket, you need simple ti add \ before the character you want  to escape

This works too, but you have some restriction in your database in this case it would be safe_mode, where you need a primary key in the WHERE clause in your case you can use *WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM smf_messages);*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE smf_messages  (id INTEGER auto_increment Primary key,
>   body VARCHAR(250)
> );
> INSERT INTO smf_messages  (id,body) VALUES (0,'[b][google]&quot;Präferenzzollsatz&quot;[/google][i][google]&quot;προτιμησιακό ποσοστό&quot;[/google], [google]&quot;προτιμησιακός δασμός&quot;[/google] [i][/b]');
> INSERT INTO smf_messages  (id,body) VALUES (0,'[google]&quot;Präferenzzollsatz&quot;[/google]');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE smf_messages SET body = REPLACE(body, '[google]&quot;', '[google]') WHERE id in (1,2,3);
> UPDATE smf_messages SET body = REPLACE(body, '&quot;[/google]', '[/google]') WHERE id in (1,2,3);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM smf_messages;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | body                                                                                                                                                               
> -: | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | [b][google]Präferenzzollsatz[/google][i][google]προτιμησιακό ποσοστό[/google], [google]προτιμησιακός δασμός[/google] [i][/b]
>  2 | [google]Präferenzzollsatz[/google]
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=88909411232d453e55d1226aa20350b7)*

Comment: That gives me the same error. No, I do not want to find a single quote; I want to find `[google]&quot;` as stated above.

Comment: As you can see in the example, i can't undestand or reprocude your problem. Your update works as intende, ypur error message doesn't fit, so make an example, where we can examine the problem

Comment: As posted earlier, you can see the issue here: https://ibb.co/ykwHCNL By the way, maybe MariaDB 10.3 works slightly differently than MySQL 5.7

Comment: no mariadb 103.3 woerks too see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d584b5508a0251668603a8871c21e86c so try to replicate your problem

Comment: I ran the query with real data https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a8ce00ad280c51c057fd0c664c4bb7ec

Comment: Not sure what I am supposed to do, I tried 
`UPDATE smf_messages SET body = REPLACE(body, '[google]&quot;', '[google]') WHERE ID_BOARD in (64);` and got same error

Comment: please post the **correct** error message. you got. further rebuild a sanitize version of your database and see if that problem happens also check for updates, sometimes it simple a bug in the software

Comment: Error found: I was testing using "Simulate query" in phpmyadmin, when I ran the query, it was executed ahead without issues.